# Appending multiple CSV to single Excel worksheet using Python Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I am stuck with a bunch of csv files (multiple columns, all with header at row 14) that I would like to append all csv's to a single excel worksheet template. The template has a header that is only a subset of the csv's, so not every column needs to be copied over. So ideally I need to be able to assign which column gets copied over to which new column..

So far, I have only been able to convert csv files to their excel counterparts...

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:/Users/abc/Desktop/Template.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
for csv_file in glob.glob(csv_dir):
    if csv_file.endswith('.csv'):
        with open(csv_file, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
            for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
                for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                    column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
                    ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = cell
    wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

Comment: You are using excel or csv files ?

Comment: could you include a small sample of your data and what your desired outcome looks like so that we re-produce the issue?

Comment: @NareshKumar I'm using both, appending multiple csv to excel spreadsheet

Comment: Why not read all the csv and save it in a dataframe which is easy to process and append the data as required and again convert it to csv or excel as needed

Answer (score -1):

This could be what you are looking for

from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas

```
csv_files = ['my_file1.csv', 'my_file2.csv', ..., 'my_file5.csv']

with ExcelWriter('my_excel.xlsx') as ew:
    for csv_file in csv_files:
        pandas.read_csv(csv_file).to_excel(ew, sheet_name=csv_file)
```

by [Everilä](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4)

Comment: It's far more efficient to go directly from CSV to Excel because these are both row-oriented formats.